# psycopg2 cursor hangs up when query time is too long

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2

I have a problem with executing long time queries using psycopg2 in Python.
When query takes more than 180 seconds the script execution hangs up for a long time.

I use `Python 3.4.3` and `psycopg2 2.6.1`.

Here are samples to reproduce the issue:

```
import psycopg2

cnn = psycopg2.connect(
    database='**********',
    user='**********',
    password='**********',
    host='**********',
    port=5432,
)
print("Connected")
cursor = cnn.cursor()
seconds = 5
print("Sleep %s seconds"%seconds)
cursor.execute("SELECT pg_sleep(%s);"%seconds)
print("Exit.")
```

Script works fine when query takes 5 seconds:

```
$python3 /tmp/test.py 
Connected
Sleep 5 seconds
Exit.
```

But when number of seconds is about 180 and greater, the line `cursor.execute` hangs up and instructions below are never executed:

```
import psycopg2

cnn = psycopg2.connect(
    database='**********',
    user='**********',
    password='**********',
    host='**********',
    port=5432,
)
print("Connected")
cursor = cnn.cursor()
seconds = 180
print("Sleep %s seconds"%seconds)
cursor.execute("SELECT pg_sleep(%s);"%seconds)
print("Exit.")
```

Here is a output (`print("Exit.")` never executed as hangs up):

```
$python3 /tmp/test.py 
Connected
Sleep 180 seconds
<Never exit>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Could it be due to a server-side  execution timeout?

Comment: @cardosource in my case – no, because the same query runs fine in pgAdmin. But it hangs when using psycopg2.

Comment: And if you set a timeout for all queries using "SET SESSION statement_timeout = 500000;", could that help?

Comment: Have you seen [Postgres closes connection during query after a few hundred seconds when using Psycopg2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56289874/postgres-closes-connection-during-query-after-a-few-hundred-seconds-when-using-p)?

Comment: @flakes thanks, I haven't. I also found this one just now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61353359/2761695

Answer (score 1):

You might have a statement timeout set somewhere. Try to turn it off for a single statement:

```
cursor = cnn.cursor()
seconds = 180

# Turn statement_timeout off for the next query
cursor.execute("SET statement_timeout = 0")

print("Sleep %s seconds"%seconds)
cursor.execute("SELECT pg_sleep(%s);"%seconds)
print("Exit.")
```

If this works, change the default, whereever you have defined it, or just for your connection:

```
cnn = psycopg2.connect(
    database='**********',
    user='**********',
    password='**********',
    host='**********',
    port=5432,
    options='-c statement_timeout=0'
)
```

Comment: But shouldn't a `QueryCanceledError` or `InternalError` be raised if the statement_timeout is reached, because it terminates the query?

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, you have to set the timeout option, because you will need the function to exit after some time.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(db_url, options='-c statement_timeout=300000')  # timout in ms
```

This works for me.