# psycopg2.OperationalError: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected django Qcluster

Tags: django, psycopg2

Hi I'm trying to run a function as a background job from Django Qcluster and that jobs run for more than an hour based on the response of that job I update my Postgres table but when I get a response from Qcluster and try to update the table it gives me this error.

How can I fix this error?

**psycopg2.OperationalError: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected.**

Qcluster setting:

```
{
  "name": "sampleapp",
  "workers": 8,
  "recycle": 500,
  "compress": true,
  "save_limit": 250,
  "queue_limit": 500,
  "cpu_affinity": 1,
  "label": "Django Q",
  "max_attempts": 1,
  "attempt_count": 1,
  "catch_up": false,
  "redis": {
     "host": "127.0.0.1",
     "port": 6379,
     "db": 0
  }
}
```

Django==3.1.7

django-q==1.3.9

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected
15:36:35 [Q] ERROR Failed [kentucky-montana-west-alaska] - connection already closed 
: Traceback (most recent call last): File 
"/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute return 
self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.OperationalError: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last): File 
"/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/connector/sync_utils.py", line 1361, in 
run_data_sync if not table_pipeline_json.count(): File 
"/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 411, in count return 
self.query.get_count(using=self.db) File 
"/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 515, in get_count number = 
obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count'] File 
"/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 500, in get_aggregation result = 
compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE) File 
"/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql 
cursor.execute(sql, params) File 
"/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute return 
super().execute(sql, params) File 
"/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/django/__init__.py", line 500, in execute return 
real_execute(self, sql, params) File 
"/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute return 
self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute) File 
"/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers return 
executor(sql, params, many, context) File 
"/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute return 
self.cursor.execute(sql, params) File 
"/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__ raise 
dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value File 
"/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute return 
self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last): File 
"/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 237, in _cursor return 
self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name)) File 
"/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner return func(*args, **kwargs) 
File "/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 236, in create_cursor cursor = 
self.connection.cursor()

psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last): File 
"/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django_q/cluster.py", line 381, in worker res = f(*task['args'], 
**task['kwargs']) File 
"/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/connector/sync_utils.py", line 1858, in 
run_data_sync save_batch_error(parent_batch_obj, response, integration_obj) File 
"/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/batchesapi/utils.py", line 13, in 
save_batch_error batch_obj.save() File 
"/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 753, in save self.save_base(using=using, 
force_insert=force_insert, File 
"/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 790, in save_base updated = 
self._save_table( File 
"/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 872, in _save_table updated = 
self._do_update(base_qs, using, pk_val, values, update_fields, File 
"/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 926, in _do_update return 
filtered._update(values) > 0 File 
"/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site-
packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 803, in _update return 
query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR) File 
"/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1522, in execute_sql cursor = 
super().execute_sql(result_type) File 
"/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1154, in execute_sql cursor = 
self.connection.cursor() File 
"/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner return func(*args, **kwargs) 
File "/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor return self._cursor() 
File "/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 237, in _cursor return 
self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name)) File 
"/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__ raise 
dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value File 
"/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 237, in _cursor return 
self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name)) File 
"/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner return func(*args, **kwargs) 
File "/mnt/c/lyftrondatasync/LyftrondatasyncAPI/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 236, in create_cursor cursor = 
self.connection.cursor()

django.db.utils.InterfaceError: connection already closed
```

Comment: My suspicion is network issues e.g. a timeout. I point you at [PostgreSQL: SSL SYSCALL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/175085/postgresql-ssl-syscall-error-eof-detected) and [psycopg2.OperationalError: SSL SYSCALL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50708914/psycopg2-operationalerror-ssl-syscall-error-eof-detected) for similar questions. See if the answers are pertinent to your situation.